# Use of null hypothesis significance testing in observational data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, experiment-design, observational-study

My question is about the use and interpretation of null hypothesis significance tests in cases where we do not have random samples or designed experiments, but rather have observational data from the full population of interest.

Let's say I have a population of 10 sensors that each record the temperature of a separate machine just before it fails.

The data may look like this:

| days_from_start | fail_temperature_celsius | sensor_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 60 | 1 |
| 2 | 25 | 2 |
| 6 | 35 | 6 |
| 30 | 120 | 3 |
| 43 | 90 | 9 |

Now let's say that an engineer suspects that the temperatures at which failures occur are trending towards higher values. They ask me to do the following analysis:

1. Split the data into two equal time intervals. For example, the last 15 days is the "current" interval, and the 15 days before that are the "baseline" interval.
2. Do a two-sample t-test to test the null hypothesis that there is no difference in means
3. If the p-value is low, conclude that there has been a practically significant increase in the temperature at which machines fail.

I feel like this is not a good approach, for several reasons. But for the purpose of this question, what I want to focus on is the lack of randomization. I believe that the two-sample t-test is most appropriate in cases where we design an experiment to gather a sample from a population, and randomly assign "treatment" to some units in that sample.

In this case, there is no clear way to divide the "sample" into two groups (why intervals of 15 days instead of 30 days?), and it seems difficult to interpret the data as a random sample from a super-population.

**Am I correct in saying that the lack of randomization would make the use of p-values inappropriate here?**

Here are some references that led me to this line of thinking:

1. [Use and Misuse of p-Values in Designed and Observational Studies: Guide for Researchers and Reviewers](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Eabe/lista/pdf5hmVFkIYwC.pdf)
2. [Can p-values be meaningfully interpreted without random sampling?](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistics-surveys/volume-14/issue-none/Can-p-values-be-meaningfully-interpreted-without-random-sampling/10.1214/20-SS129.pdf)

Comment: Seems like you are conflating problems in study design (you describe a single sample design trying to masquerade as a two sample design) with problems in hypothesis testing.

Comment: Thanks @Alexis, that's a good point. Would you see any issues with a one-sample test in this case? For example, use the t-test to test that the mean in the sample is equal to 50 degrees Celsius.

Comment: You don't use a test to see if a sample quantity has some value -- you know its value, there's nothing to infer. Testing, estimation, prediction etc is about what you have not observed or cannot observe (typically, population quantities).

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b, that makes complete sense to me. But a follow up question here: is there any reasonable interpretation such as "the last 15 days represent a sample from stochastic process 1, and the 15 days before that represent a sample from stochastic process 2. And we are testing whether the samples allow us to infer that these are two different processes."?

Comment: If they're a "non-random" sample in some sense, how do you distinguish differences due to sampling bias from real differences in the process? If you can make some model assumptions about what you're observing, then you can perhaps get somewhere. Beware also the impact of omitted variables , and (since these are time series) the issues of spurious regression/correlation with nonstationary (and indeed even non-white noise) series.

Comment: Thanks again, @Glen_b, your comments are very helpful. If you could mention these issues (and perhaps add a bit more detail) in an answer, I could accept it.

Comment: There are many posts on site discussing both omitted variable bias (/Simpson's paradox) and spurious regression (though arguably the latter in its fullest scope could encompass the former), and they are discussed on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_paradox (see especially the first diagram) and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_relationship#Examples (though as I mentioned, nonstationarity is not required to get autocorrelation-related spuriousness)